# \bfseries in makecell failure

Tags: tables, makecell

I'm trying to insert `\bfseries` to each row of a `\makecell` command, but it is not compiling. MWE below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    \makecell[{t}{>{\bfseries}l}]{Multi\\Line} \\  % error here!
  Another Line
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l}
    \makecell[{t}{l}]{Multi\\Line} \\  % works okay
    Another line
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a common formatting  of all rows of a `\makecell`, you can use `\renewcommand{\cellset}{…}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
   \renewcommand{\cellset}{\bfseries\color{red}}\makecell[tl]{Multi-\\Line} \\
\addlinespace
  Another Line \\
\addlinespace
\makecell[lt]{Another\\multi-\\line}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `makecell` has defined `\thead` for which you can define used font parameters. Using `makecell`, is advisable to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    \thead{Multi\\Line} \\   
    Another Line
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l}
    \makecell{Multi\\Line} \\   
    Another line
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: I use `booktabs` as well, which takes care of the extra spacing `\thead` would have offered if I use a rule, which is my most likely case for this, and the result is too much space. If possible, I'd like to avoid `thead`. I suppose if I have to use `thead`, I'd want to adjust the gape via `\renewcommand\theadgape{}`. I'd rather not do this though, as I made a macro to assist with `\makecell`, and would like consistent use between header or body content.

Comment: @likethevegetable, sorry, I don't follow you. Where is `booktabs`? What is actually your problem? Your use of `makecell` macros, frankly said, is far to be consistent. Please, edit your question and explain, what is your problem and what is you goal to echieve.